# how to remove punctuation errors in android via coding?

Tags: android

I am working on android applications. I am getting the data from server. But the data that is getting from server conatains some punctuation errors. How can I remove such type in android while setting the text?

Comment: Lots of negative votes but no constructive suggestions. Welcome to SO.

Comment: Agree with @WayneUroda answer. Plus, if you know all the characters that you want to replace, you can follow the answer and can replace all.

Answer (score 1):

If `'` is always replaced with `?` then you could use one of the replace functions:

```
String label = "patient?s";
String fixedLabel = label.replace('?', '\'');
```

This will replace all instances of `?` with `'` in the string.

I am not sure if this is what you are asking though?

See the string documentation:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html